# Reset Password link is wrong

Tags: members, email, solspace-user, profile-edit, forgot-password

I am using EE 2.6.1 and User 3.4.3

I have been having issues with the Forgot Password form.

The email being sent contains a link to reset the password

urlofmywebsite//436184488/reset_password?&id=TuIkrfhW

This link gives me a 404. Even when I remove the //
Also ?& seems wrong.

If anyone could tell me what is wrong with this link it would be great.

Comment: Are you using Forgot Password tag of user module (http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/forgot_password/).

Comment: Yes I am using the User Forgot Password tag. The form submits fine. It is the link in the email that is not working

Comment: I think, you should write to Solspace. Those guys are very responsive.

Comment: Not sure if you posted in the [Solspace Support Forums](http://www.solspace.com/forums/) yet, but just in case I answered below. Short version: not available yet, but we're working on it ;)

Comment: has anyone been able to solve this yet? I am using the current version of User (3.4.5) and the reset_passoword link is not found.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, and ultimately discovered it was caused by a setting in Focus Labs EE Master Config.

In config.master.php around line 258 you'll find:

`/**
 * Member-based settings
 */`

//$env_config['profile_trigger']          = rand(0,time()); // randomize the member profile trigger word because we'll never need it

I'm not sure why randomising the tigger would help, however I found that setting it to a constant fixed the problem e.g.

`$env_config['profile_trigger'] = 'member';`

Comment: I think this is referring to using the native member module, not Solspace User as the question specifies, yes?

Comment: Current versions of Solspace User reference the newer EE core forgot password routine, so both User and EE forgot password forms will send URLs as described in this answer. Right now the only fix is to change from the Focus Lab random member profile trigger to something constant - assuming your are using the Focus Lab master config.

Comment: By the way - due to a long history of spammers hitting up EE sites using the /member/register page, which is EE's default reg page for member module, I highly recommend not choosing 'member' as the trigger word. Something like member-auth or member-tools would do fine, it just has to be constant.

Comment: I hit this issue too, with Profile:Edit. Took me awhile to finally find this thread but, yes, randomizing the trigger was the issue for me as well. And I agree with @ChadCrowell that you should still use some sort of random string as to deter spammers form being able to use the default member trigger.

Answer (score 2):

In EE 2.6.1, the reset password routine works differently compared to pre-2.6 version. Instead of being sent a password reset link, followed by a generated new password by email, users receive a link by email to visit a page on EE to reset their password themselves.

As of this writing, this new password reset method isn't available in User yet, but we're working on getting this added. :)